# Hibernate envers with postgresql sees byte array as type bytea, but i expect it to be oid

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-envers

After upgrading tot spring 3 and hibernate core/envers to 6.* this issue occurs.

- Spring Boot version 3.1.4
- Hibernate core and envers version 6.2.5.Final (tried different versions)
- PostgreSQL jdbc driver version 42.6.0 (tried different versions)

I have an entity with column;

```
@Lob
private byte[] content;
```

My database table has a column named content with type oid.

Since i use envers, i also have a _aud table with a column named 'content' with type oid.

While starting up the schema validation gives the following error;

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [content] in table [xxxxx_aud]; found [oid (Types#BIGINT)], but expecting [bytea (Types#VARBINARY)]
```

If i add @NotAudited to this field, it works, so my normal table works with type OID.
I expect my hibernate envers column also to be OID, but bytea is wanted.

Do i need to convert my _aud table column content to bytea or is this a hibernate envers bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by creating a custom Converter

```
  @Converter
  public class ContentConverter implements AttributeConverter<byte[], Blob> {

  //code

  }
```

and added the annotation to the field;

```
  @Lob
  @Convert(converter = ContentConverter.class)
  private byte[] content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add an annotation

@Lob
@JdbcTypeCode(Types.BINARY)
private byte[] content;

In other hand, that mapping depend of org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect you use and its version.
You can find an answer : [Hibernate, Postgresql: Column "x" is of type oid but expression is of type byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488693/hibernate-postgresql-column-x-is-of-type-oid-but-expression-is-of-type-byte)

Comment: Thank you, this is something that i already tried, but unfortunately without success. The problem is that my normal table (oid) and my audit table (bytea) require different types, but i both want and expect them to be oid.

Comment: Yes it seems to be an envers issue, so do you try to alter column type ? Is it working ? But oid and bytea are not same it can cause bug. In fact if you don't really need OID I think that the better way is to switch all to BYTEA. Even that you can use a filesystem or other think than database to stock big files.

Comment: From my experience BYTEA column is not lazy loaded, so I do not agree with your statement to convert all lobjects to bytea, because it causes slowdown in certain usecases.